# search/filter in ojet tree view

Tags: treeview, full-text-search, filtering, oracle-jet

I am trying to implement search in tree view using OJet. Need to hide and show tree nodes based in search text, but unable to apply styles in child nodes beyond parent level. Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please show the work that you've already done, so we can help with specific things.

Comment: Tree view data is parsed from JSON file

Comment: Any update on this? Are u able to proceed? If so, please tell us how to do that.